# Client ID for Project Oxford Speech API

Tags: azure, curl, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I'd like to test Microsoft Project Oxford Speech recognition API, but I don't know where or how to get the client_id.

I'm trying to test Search API. First, I'm trying to get a token to use the service:

```
curl -d -i "https://oxford-speech.cloudapp.net/token/issueToken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=123&client_secret=456scope=https%3A%2F%2Fspeech.platform.bing.com"
{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key." }
```

I have primary and secondary keys, but I can't find client_id. Can someone help?

Comment: Isn't it the same as azure's userId?

Comment: I tried my e-mail address as Client_id which I use to log in into Azure - doesn't work...

Answer (score 5):

See here

// Note: Sign up at http://www.projectoxford.ai to get a subscription key.  Search for Speech APIs from Azure Marketplace.
            // Use the subscription key as Client secret below.
            Authentication auth = new Authentication("Come up with a short ClientId", "Client Secret");

More instructions here http://www.projectoxford.ai/doc/general/subscription-key-mgmt

Comment: >> Come up with a short ClientId

So I tried this:

curl -d -i "https://oxford-speech.cloudapp.net/token/issueToken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=123666666&client_secret=<my secret key>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fspeech.platform.bing.com"

and 

Also with (client_id=tomas0413)


And in both cases I get:

{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key." }

Comment: Once you have this information, this command should work: curl -v -X POST "https://api.projectoxford.ai/speech/v0/internalIssueToken" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <Your primary subscription key> --data-ascii "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<your client ID generated from Azure>&client_secret=<your primary subscription key>&scope=https://speech.platform.bing.com"

Answer (score 0):

1. goto the following link [Subscribe to speech control](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/speechcontrol) and subscribe to speech recognition control...
2. register a new app using this [link](https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications/) and here you can give the CLIENT ID of your choice which will be later used in the app..
3. finally goto the following link [www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/subscriptions]  sign in with a Microsoft account and find subscription key for any any api you wanna use and use this key as CLIENT SECRET
4. Hope this will help as I have tested this and it works perfectly for me...
5. third link is in brackets as i wasn't allowed more than 2 links...

Answer (score -1):

After you signed up for the Speech API, you can view your subscription keys using this link: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/subscriptions.

```
Authentication auth = new Authentication("Come up with a short ClientId", "Client Secret");
```

In your code, DO NOT come up with a short ClientId. Just replace "Come up with a short ClientId" with the first key you find on the subscription page and replace "Client Secret" with the second key you find on the subscription page.