# Microsoft Bing speech recognition, What is Cliend-id and Client secret?

Tags: client, speech-recognition, bing, azure-cognitive-services

I'm sorry to ask you such an idiot question, but a read all the post about this topic, and I'm still stuck with my problem. I'm using **pyoxford** because I want to use microsoft bing speech recognition. But each time I try to use my program, the response is:

```
HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
```

requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Access Denied

Here is my program:

```
import pyoxford

text="welcome"
api=pyoxford.speech("client id","Client secret")

binary=api.text_to_speech(text)
with open("voice.wav","wb") as f:
    f.write(binary)

recognized =api.speech_to_text("voice.wav")
if text==recognized:
          print("bravo")
```

and here the documentation of [pyoxford](https://github.com/icoxfog417/pyoxford).

I think the problem come from my **id_client** or my **client secret**. I tried:

```
(id_client=Bing speech preview key1 / client_secret=bing speech preview key 2)

(id_client=Bing speech preview key2 / client_secret=bing speech preview key 1)

(id_client=my name / client_secret=bing speech preview key 1)

(id_client=microsoft data market account id / client_secret=bing speech preview key 1)
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client ID for Project Oxford Speech API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085058/client-id-for-project-oxford-speech-api)

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your inquiry. The client-id can be your appname and client key is the subscription key you got during registration.